# Using a delimiter on a string in a console then setting it to a variable

Tags: java

I need help splitting a string contained in a variable (that's contained in a scanner) using a delimiter and then setting another string variable to the delimited string.

This is what i have been trying so far but it doesn't work:

// console3 would be set to a variable containing a string

```
console3.useDelimiter(delimiter1);
X = console3.next();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
string[] parts = console3.split(delimiter1);

for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    //do something with parts[i]
}
```